# how do I distinguish between longpress and singletap in android?

Tags: android, click, gesture, ontouchlistener, tap

I have a card game where i want single tap to do action on card, and longpress on card shows me bigger image of a card. I know there is GestureListener, but how do I use it? here is my code:

```
gd = new GestureDetector(this, this);


    gd.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener()  
    {  
        @Override  
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)  
        {  
            Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onDoubleTap");
            return false;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e)  
        {  
            Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onDoubleTapEvent");
            //if the second tap hadn't been released and it's being moved  
            if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)  
            {  

            }  
            else if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)//user released the screen  
            {  

            }  
            return false;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e)  
        {  
            Log.d("OnDoubleTapListener", "onSingleTapConfirmed");
            return false;  
        }  
    });
```

Comment: you could give [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) a try

Answer (score 2):

errr... yourCard.setOnLongClickListener() ?